# Colocar getdate () con fecha Perú

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, select, date, sql

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en **SqlServer** en el que le envío como fecha **getdate()**, el problema está cuando la fecha que debe indicar es relacionada a **Perú** y **el servidor se encuentra en Chile**. existe alguna manera de enviarle el parámetro sin restarle las horas de diferencia a la fecha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cómo el servidor se encuentra en el País de Chile, al momento de realizar getDate(), te publicará la fecha actual del País Chile.

Existe varías manera de implementar:

- Setear la fecha correspondiente del servido SQL Server a la de perú (No es recomendable, debido por la complejidad que se tiene).
- Realizar una Función parametrizable (La solución que te daré), sin embargo allí caes con la misma lógica de restar la diferencia de fecha (Con la servidor y el país que te encuentres).

1) Como primer paso te recomienda crear una tabla global, llamada: **TimeOffset**, la cual te almacenará las diferencias de Horas, cabe mencionar que dicha tabla contiene las siguientes columnas: Location (Llave primaria), y TimeOffset (Diferencia de horario).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeOffsets](
      [Location] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
      [TimeOffset] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TimeOffsets] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
 (
       [Location] ASC
 )
 WITH 
 (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2) Posteriormente [Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manisblog/2009/06/16/how-to-get-the-current-time-of-any-timezone-in-sql-server-2008/) (Ver URL), te proporciona información correspondiente para llenar la respectiva tabla:

[image: Tabla de diferencias de horarios]

3) Posteriormente crea una Función global (En SQLServer), que te permita calcular la diferencia entre dos Lugares (En este caso, El servidor de Chile y Perú):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetGeographicalTime
(
      @MyPlace AS VARCHAR(100),
      @TargetPlace AS VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS DATETIMEOFFSET
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @TargetPlaceOffset VARCHAR(100)
      DECLARE @MyPlaceOffset VARCHAR(100)
      DECLARE @todaysDateTime Datetime2
      DECLARE @todaysDateTimeOffset DateTimeOffset
      DECLARE @returnDateTimeOffset DateTimeOffset
      SELECT @todaysDateTime = GetDate()
      SELECT @MyPlaceOffset =[TIMEOFFSET] from TIMEOFFSETS WHERE [LOCATION] = @MyPlace
      SELECT @TargetPlaceOffset = [TIMEOFFSET] from TIMEOFFSETS WHERE [LOCATION] = @TargetPlace
      SELECT @todaysDateTimeOffset = TODATETIMEOFFSET (@todaysDateTime, @MyPlaceOffset)
      SELECT @returnDateTimeOffset = SWITCHOFFSET(@todaysDateTimeOffset,@TargetPlaceOffset)
      RETURN @returnDateTimeOffset
END
```

4) Finalmente llamas a la función que te calcula la diferencia de horario, en tu caso sería

```
Select dbo.GetGeographicalTime('Santiago','Lima')
```

Comment: Muchas Diego, y esto funcionará bien para el cambio de horario por ejemplo en Chile el 12 de mayo se resto un hora por horario invierno pero esta se vuelve aumentar en agosto.

Comment: Funciona, si solo sí le das mantenimiento a la tabla 'TimeOffset', la cual ahora se encuentra Santiago -04:00, pero si le resta una hora debe modificar dicho registro a Santiago -05:00.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el parámetro **AT TIME ZONE**

```
select  getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'   as FechaPac,
        getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' AS FechaEur
```

O puedes utilizar un datediff si la diferencia en horas será siempre la misma

```
select Datediff(hour, fecha1, fecha2)
```

Para mayor detalle puedes ver la url:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: AT TIME ZONE no me funciona estoy con sql server 2008

Comment: Entonces debes utilizar el datediff

Answer (score 0):

Una forma simple sería la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @SrcOffset INT
DECLARE @DstOffset INT
DECLARE @Now       DATETIME

SELECT  @SrcOffset = DATEPART(TZ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()),
        @DstOffset = -300,
        @Now       = GETDATE()  

SELECT  @Now                                            AS 'LocalDate',
        DATEADD(MINUTE, @DstOffset - @SrcOffset, @Now)  AS 'PeruDate'
```

Básicamente se obtiene por `DATEPART(TZ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())` la zona horaria del servidor en minutos, y en `@DstOffset` configuramos la que le correspondería a Perú, la diferencia se la suma en minutos al `GETDATE()` (hora server), y con esto obtendríamos la hora deseada. Lo que es importante notar, que los horarios de verano locales en Chile, me imagino que son actualizados a nivel servidor, de forma tal que `@SrcOffset` debiera ser el correcto, pero el de Perú, eventualmente debiera ser ajustado, -300 (5 horas) es el actual, -360 para (-6 horas utc) o -240 (-4 horas utc). Las funciones [`DATEPART`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Y [`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) son compatibles con 2008.

Answer (score -2):

A ver, lo mejor es utilizar un case, si sabes la fecha en que se cambia el horario. Utilizas case y between en función de la fecha actual con curdate() y agregas cuántas horas sumar.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/349314)