# Obtener fecha actual de zona horaria America Lima en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo mi base de datos alojada en un hosting y al momento de obtener la fecha y hora actual con la funcion GETDATE()  me trae el tiempo con dos horas de retraso. Esto a que se debe ? y como puedo obtener el tiempo actual de mi zona horaria "America/Lima".

Comment: que version de SQL Server utilizas?

Comment: Prueba SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

Comment: Tengo la version Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0

Comment: @Brais no me funciona SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164277/colocar-getdate-con-fecha-per%c3%ba/164332#164332

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono @Patricio Moracho